# PLSQL DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST and Autonoumous Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

If the main transaction issues a DBMS_LOCK.Request for a session in exclusive mode, is this lock available if that transaction enters a autonomous procedure(which I think is itself an independent transaction) in Oracle 11g?

Answer (score 1):

Yes..When you declare a stored proc to be PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION, it is essentially the same as if you logged in as the same user but in a different session.

For example, if I have two sqlplus sessions running as user a, if I do an update in session1 and a delete and commit in session 2 I can still rollback in session 1.

Assume the scenario:

```
session1> SELECT * FROM t;

session1> LOCK TABLE t IN EXCLUSIVE MODE nowait;

session1> UPDATE t SET descr = 'Un' WHERE id = 1;
```

I haven't committed yet. Now in another session(autonomous transaction):

```
session2> UPDATE t SET descr = 'Deux' WHERE id = 2;
```

Session 2 is still waiting on the commit from session 1. Therefore, I cannot get to commit the autonomous transaction which would return control to session1
.

Comment: What do you mean by "Session 1 is still waiting on the commit from session 1. Therefore, I cannot get to commit the autonomous transaction which would return control to session1" so I can't issue a commit in session2?

Comment: Silly typo mistake here..I mean to say "Session 2 is still waiting on the commit from session 1. Therefore, I cannot get to commit the autonomous transaction which would return control to session1 .